# why is nextauth (version 5 beta) not working properly after vercel deployment saying "task timed error" and "function invocation error"?

Tags: deployment, timeout, vercel, next-auth

I'm trying to test out `nextauth v5 beta version` to check authentication in a simple project. Basically in local environment, my `nextauth v5` is working completely fine without any errors (many times I have tried). I'm using credential authentication by the way. but whenever I deployed that to production to see if that works perfectly or not, my project gets deployed. Seemed fine, but whenever I try to authenticate in production, I don't know why does that take so long because it does not take that long in my local environment. I don't know I get this error saying

```
"task timed out error"
"function invocation timeout error"
"an error occured with vercel deployment"
```

like this. I have no clue what is happening. I'm banging my head around for the last couple days.

I tried to make sure every environment variables has been passed to production and I check the runtime and build logs; they are saying *"task timeout error"*. like this. But in local dev works completely fine (I'm working with credentials provider in `nextauth beta v5 version`)